# VirtualBox problem: cannot take snapshot

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, snapshot, ubuntu-10.04

I have just setup a Lucid Lynx desktop machine. I have installed VirtualBox 3.2.6 on this machine to run several server.
I have created a new Lucid Lynx server in one VM, the VM creation is fine but when I try to take a snapshot, it seems the action starts but never ends...
The desktop machine is in ext4.

Is this a know problem ?

Thanks a lot,

Luc

Answer (score 1):

You should probably start by taking a closer look at your snapshot directories for the obvious (enough available space, rights, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Nope, mine works perfectly. I suspect you do not have permissions on your snapshot folder which, if you have not changed anything, will be: ~/VirtualBox/Machines/.

Also make sure that you belong to the vboxusers group.

Comment: hello, sorry for my late reply. No, this was not linked to the permission. In fact, I think this was linked to the drive still attached to the VM when I did the snapshot.